# Style sheets refusing to load on the browser

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have downloaded an html template online. And I have gone ahead and pasted the index.html to my templates folder, and the assets to my static files, and I have placed the '{% load static %)' tag inside my index file.

Here is a snippet of the index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>ClassiGrids - Classified Ads and Listing Website Template.</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'assets/images/favicon.svg' %}" />
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <!-- Web Font -->
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ========================= CSS here ========================= -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/LineIcons.2.0.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/animate.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/tiny-slider.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/glightbox.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/main.css' %}" />

</head>

<body>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
      <p class="browserupgrade">
        You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please
        <a href="https://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve
        your experience and security.
      </p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Preloader -->
    <div class="preloader">
        <div class="preloader-inner">
            <div class="preloader-icon">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /End Preloader -->
```

I have also edited the settings to show where my template files are located

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/ 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

However, the site is still appearing in plain html on the browser. What could I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I forgot to edit the settings to include the static files, by importing the operating system

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
```

and adding the static files directory at the bottom

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```